# WPF/.NET: Can I not replace concrete classes completely by fake mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, unit-testing, moq

I have this large legacy WPF application that has no unit testing being done, and huge amount of dependencies all over the place. I'm trying to use Moq to create unit tests, but it doesn't help me much, when so many (=almost all) classes create dependencies internally, so I have no way to inject my mock objects instead of real references.

In C++ you could just write your own fake classes and make sure they are included before the real ones in the test project --> that way **all references** throughout the project could be made to refer the fake object, including all internally made references.

Is there no way in .NET to accomplish the same?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

-Seppo

P.S. This is a follow-up on an earlier question [NUnit/Moq: I have mocked a class but real contructor is executed, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24504730/nunit-moq-i-have-mocked-a-class-but-real-contructor-is-executed-why).

Comment: I'm just thinking of all the things I can not do. Yep, I can definitely not do them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Shims and Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) should do what you want it to do, but it's only available on Visual Studio Ultimate and Premium.

Beyond MS Fakes/Shims, there isn't anything in C# out of the box (or any free libraries I'm aware of) that would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a "partial mock". Say your class A creates an instance of class B internally in a [test unfriendly construct](http://www.horsdal-consult.dk/2011/02/testable-c-or-c-tufs-and-tucs.html), for example a private method.

You can move that new ClassB() to a factory method `protected virtual` method CreateClassB(...) and then use Moq's [CallBase](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/PartialMocks.aspx).

So if you are testing ClassA's MethodA

```
[Test]
public void MethodA_StateThatYouAreTesting_ExpectedResult()
{
    var partialMockA = new Mock<ClassA>{CallBase=true};
    var stubB = new Mock<ClassB>();
    stubB.Setup(b => b.SomeMethod()).Returns(SomeValue);
    parialMockA.Setup(a => a.CreateClassB()).Returns(stubB.Object);

    var result = partialMock.MethodA();

    Assert.AreEqual(someExpectedValue, result);
}
```

This saves you the extra step of creating an interface for ClassB. I believe this is reasonable in situations where the code you inherited is not well structured, and ClassB  should actually be broken down in several classes and corresponding interfaces (i.e., does not follow the single responsibility principle). I like to think of this as a first step in re-factoring.

Also, an alternative to Fakes is [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page). Never used it, but since it's from Roy Osherove (the guy that wrote The Art of Unit Testing) it is probably a safe bet.